# Implication inside set builder notation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[ Edited ] 
 A candidate at the Presidential Elections , representing the Intellectual-Leftwing-Party, adopts as slogan :

" Any person should vote for me just in case 
     if she studied at Harvard , she has earned a PhD "

According to this slogan, the set of people that should vote for this candidate is :

```
          { x |  x studied at Harvard  --> x has earned a PhD }
```

From the point of view of logic is this candidate too elitist to win?

Who should vote for him according to that slogan?

Comment: Nothing in the rule set describes conditions on non-girls, so there can be boy musicians and boy non-musicians.

Comment: Sets are mathematical objects which model the notion of a collection of other mathematical objects. As such, in order for the collection you describe to be a set, girls and musicians need to be mathematical objects, to the best of my knowledge, this is not the case.

Comment: Yes. $\text {Socrates} \in \{ x \mid x \text { is a girl } \to x \text { is a musician} \}$.

Comment: Bob is being sexist. The only girls which are allowed to attend are musicians, but everything which isn't a girl is free to attend his party. I wouldn't be friends with Bob.

Comment: Asked around an hour later at https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/15435/77.

Answer (score 1):

A deaf dog can attend Bob's party.

Comment: Your answer could be interpreted by a beginner as meaning that the set defined is the universal set. ( I voted up however).

Comment: The formula in the body of the question defines a subset of the set of persons. So the answer is correct assuming a dog is a person.

Comment: I am not an enthusiast supporter of Descartes' animal-machine theory.

Comment: Let's avoid opinion based commentaries. ( But I respect your opinion SilverDoe).